# python output text similarity

Tags: python, nlp, levenshtein-distance

I have some strings need to group them together.

```
['Aus Super', 'Aus super', 'Aust Super', 'Australian Super', 'LG Super', 'Korean LG Super', 'Q Super']
```

I want to have three groups:

```
['Aus Super', 'Aus super', 'Aust Super', 'Australian Super']
['LG Super', 'Korean LG Super']
['Q Super']
```

I tried below code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

listItem = ['Aus Super', 'Aus super', 'Aust Super', 'Australian Super', 'LG Super', 'Korean LG Super', 'Q Super']

for l in listItem: 
    print(l, fuzz.token_set_ratio(l, 'LG Super'))
```

result is as below: 
[image]

based on the score 'Q Super' and 'LG Super' will be grouped together with 'Aus Super', not 'Australian Super'.

I tried levenshtein distance as well, still not good, because distinct between 'Aust' and 'Australian' is 5, while distance between 'Aust' and 'Q' is 4.

could anybody help? Thank you.

Comment: Please, submit the results as text format (use the "code" formatting.
What are you exactly trying to accomplish?
getting all the strings in one list or appending them to different lists, based on a keyword?

Comment: You should use a weighted levenshtein algorithm to fit it to your purpose: https://pypi.org/project/weighted-levenshtein/ (this library is from google - never tried it myself).

Comment: @thenewguyhere I tried to use text format, but kept on getting error and not allow me to post until I fix format as above. I tried to group similar string as three lists showed in above.